How does extensionality demand the existence of objects for which it does not supply a definition?
From Moschovakis, Notes On Set theory, p. 111:

The Axiom of Choice is different in form from the earlier “constructive”
axioms (II) – (VI), because it postulates directly the existence of a set for
which it does not supply a definition. Each of (II) – (VI) grants sethood to
a specific, explicitly defined collection of objects, it legitimizes a special case
of the most appealing (if false) General Comprehension Principle 3.3. The
Axiom of Choice is the only Zermelo axiom other than Extensionality which is
not a special case of the General Comprehension Principle. This is misstated on
occasion, to make the claim that the Axiom of Choice is the only one which
demands the existence of objects for which it does not supply a definition,
which is not true: the Extensionality and Powerset Axioms do the same, in a
more fundamental if indirect manner.

What does Moschovakis mean by this last part I boldfaced? Powerset conjures up a bunch of sets not necessarily there before, not all of which are power sets, so probably that's what he's talking about with that one. But what about extensionality? I don't normally think of that as demanding the existence of anything, directly or indirectly.

Relevant definitions:
Moschovakis is a bit idiosyncratic in his presentation in general, but the way he states the axioms is pretty typical (from p 24-25):

(I) The axiom of extensionality. For any two sets $A, B$ $$ A=B\iff \forall x (x\in A \iff x\in B)$$
(IV) Powerset axiom. For each set $A$, there exists a set $B$ whose members are exactly the subsets of $A$, i.e. $$ X\in B\iff \operatorname{Set}(X)\land X\subseteq A$$

Note however by the "set" predicate, he is open to the existence of urelements.

How does Moschovakis define Extensionality?

@RobertShore I edited it into the question,

I don't understand the downvote, but also I don't understand what Yiannis means.

@spaceisdarkgreen While i cant see why extensionality demands the existence of objects. Extensionality in a sense does ban the existence of ur-elements if say that for all urelements u $\neg\exists y[y\in u]$ so if you take that option then all ur-elements are just equivalent to the empty set. While Power set is directly saying that a set exists that didnt necessarily exist before, but this is true of union, seperation and replacement. Hope this at least helps a little.

One possible interpretation is that, if two sets are distinct, then extensionality says that there exists an element in one that is not in the other.  That element might not be definable, even  if the original two distinct sets were definable.

I'm genuinely confused how this got a vote to close for lacking context.

"The Axiom of Choice is the only Zermelo axiom other than Extensionality which is not a special case..." My personal reading is that both Choice and Extensionalty are not special cases of Comprehension, which seems true. For me, the puzzling point is that according to M's point of view, also Powerset is not a special case.

If so, I agree with you: why the "naive" formulation: $\mathcal P(A) = { X \mid X \subseteq A }$ does not "fit" with Comprehension?
